# Magmi does not import all the text from description column

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a CSV file that contains between others column the column `description` of the products in html format (the csv values are enclosed in ").

The problem is that not all the HTML text is imported in magento description field and that causes design problems when displaying the product to the customer, for example not closing the last `div`.

I use the last version of magmi and magento 1.8.0.0.

I put below a link to my csv file (after import check for example SKU=MRK17763) and see if the description in magento is complete (like in the csv) 
[fisier_csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82820736/import_marko_12_iulie_bun_openoffice.csv)

There are some limitation somewhere because when I enter the value directly in magento admin I can save the full value.

Comment: Does it happen for all your descriptions or just some of them? If the latter, can you give examples of those that work and those that don't? You have a lot of " in your description which might confuse things. As a simple test, have you tried just deleting the " to see if the description imports completely?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the line record that it's not working on, and not your full CSV?  Narrow down the issue to the problem items, include only one problem item in a CSV and remove data and test import.  Eventually you will narrow down the cause of the issue.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for my late response, I was in holiday for 2 weeks. As I said in my post take for example the line of sku=MRK17763 and try to import it. The problem is at description field. As much as I was able to see the problem is cause to the lenght of the description. If I cut the description value and paste directly in magento the product is saved, so is not a problem of magento database limitation and the issue is when is imported using magmi. Thanks

Comment: Using Magmi the value is imported but not completely and is trimmed. I did not test if is always cut after a specific number of characters. In my example (sku=MRK17763) the description field is trimmed after the words "90 -". Thanks

Comment: Go back to my original comment.  ONLY import the row that is causing the issue, then remove data from that row until the issue is fixed.  You'll eventually narrow down to the cause of the problem.